# atomicassets mintasset in contract

Tags: eosio-code, eosio-cpp

I am trying to mint an NFT as a reward for player via the smart contract, here is my code.

```
eosio::action mint_action = eosio::action(
 eosio::permission_level(_self, eosio::name("active")),
 "atomicassets"_n,
 "mintasset"_n,
 std::make_tuple(_self, collection_name, schema_name, template_id, recipient, [],  [],  []));

mint_action.send();
```

I am encountering this problem:

```
error: expected body of lambda expression
            std::make_tuple(_self, collection_name, schema_name, template_id, recipient, [],  [],  []));
```

So the last 3 parameters for minting on atomicassets are to be filled with empty arrays but the problem is I can't put empty arrays here. I'm not really good at C++ so excuse me if this is a very newb problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The very kind and helpful includenull has answered my question on the wax discord but I'll post the answer here for anyone who had the same issues.

```
action(
  permission_level(get_self(), "active"_n),
  "atomicassets"_n,
  "mintasset"_n,
  std::make_tuple(
    get_self(), // authorized_minter
    "collection"_n, // collection_name
    "schema"_n, // schema_name
    123456, // template_id
    "account"_n, // new_asset_owner
    std::map<std::string, atomicassets::ATOMIC_ATTRIBUTE>(), // immutable_data
    std::map<std::string, atomicassets::ATOMIC_ATTRIBUTE>(), // mutable_data
    std::vector<asset>(), // tokens_to_back
  )
).send();
```

You should also include the atomicassets header file if you have not already
https://github.com/pinknetworkx/atomicassets-contract/blob/master/include/atomicassets-interface.hpp

Comment: that almost worked but whenever i try to fire the action it says transaction ```
declares authority '{"actor":"cryptocraft1","permission":"owner"}', but does not have signatures for it under a provided delay of 0 ms, provided permissions [{"actor":"cryptocraft1","permission":"eosio.code"}], provided keys [], and a delay max limit of 3888000000 ms
```
how do i get it to show the signatures?

Comment: I think the error is telling you that you need to set eosio code permission for your cryptocraft1@owner account. 

This is how you do it on testnet using cleos:
cleos -u https://testnet.waxsweden.org set account permission cryptocraft1 active --add-code -p cryptocraft1@owner

You of course need cryptocraft unlocked in your wallet